# iphone-while clicking navigation bar anywhere page redirects to previous page

Tags: iphone

i have a back button in left side of navigation bar.......and i pass the action for back button as pop view controller.... while i click in navigation bar , the back button action calls.......how to restrict.......while i clicking navigation bar.....pls help me......

Answer (score 0):

Use below in your **UIViewController** inherited class,

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```